# Changing language in electron app (i18n-react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, templates, internationalization, electron

I am developing an Electron React/Redux app, which needs to be able to change language on the fly. Currently we are storing some strings as constants (for components that are not React components, for example dialog box contents) and also we have a menu that is generated from a template (see below).
We are currently using i18n-react library, which seemed easy to use and supports some advanced features like pluralization etc. This is an example of loading english translations for our menu:

```
import T from 'i18n-react';
T.setTexts({
  menu: {
    file: {
      label: '&File',
      new: '&New...',
      open: '&Open...',
      // etc.
    }
  }
});
```

This would then be the template for the menu:

```
const template = [{
  label: T.translate('menu.file.label'), //'&File'
  submenu: [{
    label: T.translate('menu.file.new'), //'&New...'
    accelerator: 'Ctrl+N',
    click: () => { /*some code*/ },
  }],
  // etc.
}]
const menu = Electron.remote.Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Electron.remote.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

The problem is that the translated strings are just that - ordinary constant strings. So when we change the language on the fly (using T.setTexts), the strings are not going to change. The react components are (probably) fine, because they store an object, not just a string (example from docs):

```
React.render(
  <T.span text={{ key: "greeting", myName: "i18n-react" }}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But how do I convince the electron menu, dialog boxes etc. to change?

Answer (score 0):

Not want to judge on i18n-react but that library might not provide a rerender on language change - as it was not meant to be used for that - only providing a translate in the language provided on initial setText.

You might look into https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next which is more mature and supports that usecase out of the box.